# Why can't I update the object in mongoose when new action has been taken?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

So, basically i have this method which uploads an image using mulder, then sends a response and creates a copy for it.

The idea is to be able to update my database entry using an update method.

Here's the schema:

```
const pictureSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, maxlength: [50, 'Title must be longer than 50 characters']},
    description: {type: String},
    filename: {type: String},
    thumbname:{type: String},
    thumbswitch:{type: Boolean, default: false},
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}
});

var picture = mongoose.model('Picture', pictureSchema);

exports.picture = picture;
```

And here's the actual method:

```
pics.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    upload.single('image')(req, res, (err) => {
      if(err){
        return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
      } else {
        if(req.file == undefined){
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'upload a valid file!' });
        } else {
          let pic = new picture({
            title: req.body.title,
            description: req.body.description,
            filename: req.body.databasepicname,
            user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)
          });
          pic.save()
          .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: pic }))
          .then(() => gm(path.resolve('./storage/media/' + req.body.databasepicname))      //// TODO: establish correct routes, 
          .resize(120, null)
            .write(path.resolve('./storage/media/thumb' + '-' + req.body.databasepicname), function (err) {
              if (!err) {
                console.log('thumbnail created successfully')

                //THE PROBLEM IS HERE. HOW DO I UPDATE THE pic object?
                pic.update($set{thumbname: 'thumb' + '-' + req.body.databasepicname,
                            thumbswitch: true})
                pic.save().then(() => console.log(pic))
                }
              else{console.log(err)}
            })
          )
          };
        }
      });
  });
```

Here's the output I'm obtaining from logging the pic after trying to modify the object.

```
{ thumbswitch: false,
  _id: 5ce85e820f08d96713c6dc73,
  title: 'botty',
  description: 'lorem ipsum blah',
  filename: 'image-1558732418894.jpg',
  user: 5ce85e820f08d96713c6dc72,
  __v: 0 }
```

Here's the output I'm hoping for:

```
{ thumbswitch: true,
  _id: 5ce85e820f08d96713c6dc73,
  title: 'botty',
  description: 'lorem ipsum blah',
  filename: 'image-1558732418894.jpg',
  thumbname: 'thumb-image-1558732418894.jpg',
  user: 5ce85e820f08d96713c6dc72,
  __v: 0 }
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: can you update the question with the output of an above query and expected output..?
I feel the issue is in pic.update right.?

Comment: Why don't you create a copy and then send response?

Comment: It was in the requirements that the api send the response and then create a copy